# How to convert ReadOnlyMemory to IMemoryOwner?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm planning to use a data structure that is essentially as like

```
public readonly struct Wrapper //: IDisposable, IEquatable<Wrapper>, ...
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The actual data.
    /// </summary>
    private IMemoryOwner<byte> Data { get; }

    public Wrapper(IMemoryOwner<byte> data)
    {
       Data = data;
    }

    public Wrapper(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

to wrap memory that may be pooled using `MemoryPool<byte>`, hence having a type of `IMemoryOwner`, or `ArrayPool<byte>`, or allocated with `var someData = new byte[0];`.

The idea is to provide a more convenient access to what would otherwise be chunks of bytes allocated ad hoc or leased from a pool of some sort. This byte data would have certain patterns (checked in constructor) and may vary in length.

Consuming either `IMemoryOwner` or `ReadOnlyMemory` implies taking ownership of the data and disposal would return it to a pool if leased, so it looks like this design is sound from that perspective.

But have I overlooked something since it doesn't appear to be straightforward to make `ReadOnlyMemory` into `IMemoryOwner`? How could that be achieved?

`ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` captures the intent of immutable memory store, but not who owns the memory otherwise than that assuming ownership of it when provided as a constructor parameter.

<edit: Considering the memory layout, maybe the wrapped type should be `ReadOnlyMemory` and/or the type should inherit from `IMemoryOwner` and maybe a custom memory pool implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It appears going with custom pool is the choice here. Specifically at https://gist.github.com/GrabYourPitchforks/8efb15abbd90bc5b128f64981766e834 the `NonAllocatingPool<T> : MemoryPool<T>` is the choice for this occasion.